# Type is not resolved for member Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm publishing a project that includes the nuget package for Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication. I've verified that this package was restored and installed during the 'Nuget restore' portion of the publishing. When it begins to build, I receive the error

> Error ASPRUNTIME: Type is not resolved for member 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException,Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication, Version=1.3.1.0

The strange thing is we are able to deploy our project through visual studio without any issues. This is only occurring in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in the nuget package regarding precompilation. Setting PrecompileBeforePublish to False fixed this issue.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing here and please [accept it as self-answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so that your answer can help other community members to search this useful information more easily! It just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's related to the agent you're using on your build definition. Try to change to a different one, and it should work as expected.